# Rails: Return uniq results using two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After the user submits a search, I'd like to show a history of what companies have made the same search and in what day. Let me explain...

I have a `searches` table like so:

```
id   user_id   date          query
1    1         01-01-2015    A457263
2    1         01-01-2015    A457263
3    2         01-01-2015    A457263
4    3         01-01-2015    A457263
5    3         02-01-2015    A457263
```

and the `users` belong to a company:

```
id   company_id
1    1
2    1
3    2

id   name
1    Company One
2    Company Two
```

Now what I'd like to do is select all searches made for that specific query `A457263`. Im assuming its:

```
query = params[:query]
@history = Search.where("query = ?", query)
```

And then filter out the repeated searches made by users in the same company on the same day.

So the final result will look like this:

```
id    user_id    date         query
1     1          01-01-2015   A457263
4     3          01-01-2015   A457263
5     3          02-01-2015   A457263
```

I've been messing around with the uniq method but I can't get around it this time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [group](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) by company ids and search date.

```
@history = Search.includes(:user).where("searches.query = ?", query).group("users.company_id, searches.date")
```

`includes` give you access to the user table, which allows you to group by the company ID. `group` ensures that you only get one record for each company id and search date.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
@history = Search.joins(:users).where("searches.query = ?", query).uniq.group("users.company_id, searches.date")
```